# Translating an interview, stuck on one part where "いたいけなこと" is discussed

Tags: meaning

I'm translating an interview with a manga artist, and there's a part that I don't understand. He's talking about the violence in his manga.

> 作家：　作家は思った以上にフィクションと現実を分けてますから。そこに描かれたことは別に俺の願望でもなければ、そういうやり方を世の中に示唆したつもりもないんですけど。話のために、いたいけなことをさせてしまったというのもあるので。
>
> 編集者：　そうですよね。今回の主人公もやはりいたいけな目にあうんでしょうか？

I don't understand the "いたいけなことをさせてしまったというのもあるので" bit. What might いたいけなこと mean in this context?

Comment: "pity-inducing things"

Answer (score 1):

As user4032 said in the comments, it seems to be [pitiable, young(and helpless)](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/3329/m0u/%E5%B9%BC%E6%B0%97/)

Comment: This link doesn't work. it says"Page not found" as first link (非回答者）

Comment: @Qwj_38 Oh the user who went by 非回答者 has deleted their account. I believe the link is just a link to the comment under the question. And 非回答者 refers to user4032

Comment: Yes I think so, and thank you for editing this answer.